# Displaying popups based on the user buttons selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I want to do here is whenever the user selects their choice of a specific component a corresponding popup is displayed according to the selected buttons/choices.

But, so far I couldn't bind the specific buttons as well as the I keep getting the two popups whenever I press the recommended button

basically, I'm trying to do something like this

[image]

[image]

Here's my code:

```js
//choices buttons
const mainbtnEL_1 = document.querySelectorAll(".btn__001");
mainbtnEL_1.forEach(btnEl => {
  btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector('.special__1')?.classList.remove('special__1');

    btnEl.classList.add('special__1');
  });
});
const mainbtnEL_2 = document.querySelectorAll(".btn__002");
mainbtnEL_2.forEach(btnEl => {
  btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector('.special__2')?.classList.remove('special__2');

    btnEl.classList.add('special__2');
  });
});
//pop up
function open__Popup() {
  popup.classList.add('open-Popup');
}
function close__Popup() {
  popup.classList.remove('open-Popup');
}
let popup__2 = document.getElementById("popup__2");
function open__Popup2() {
  popup__2.classList.add('open-Popup');
}
function close__Popup2() {
  popup__2.classList.remove('open-Popup');
}
```

```css
.special__1 {
  background-color: #4837ff;
}

.special__2 {
  background-color: #4837ff;
}

.popup {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
  color: #333;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.open-Popup {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.table__1 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.main__img_1 {
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(8, 218, 255, 0.6);
}

.close__btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 80px;
  background: hsla(204, 100%, 15%, 0.286);
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<h2> Choose your CPU </h2>
<div class="mainbtn__1">
  <button type="button" class="btn__001" id="AMD">AMD</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn__001" id="Intel">Intel</button>
</div>

<h2> Choose your GPU </h2>
<div class="mainbtn__2">
  <button type="button" class="btn__002" id="RTX3060">RTX3060</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn__002" id="RTX3050">RTX3050</button>
</div>

<div class="popup__container">

  <button type="submit" class="popup__btn" id="recommended" onclick="open__Popup(); open__Popup2()">Recommended</button>

  <!-- FIRST popup page -->
  <div class="popup" id="popup">
    <table class="table__1" id="tb_1">
      <tr>
        <td>CPU</td>
        <td>AMD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>GPU</td>
        <td>RTX3060</td>
      </tr>

    </table>"
    <button type="button" class="close__btn" onclick="close__Popup()">Close</button>
  </div>


  <!-- second popup page -->
  <div class="popup" id="popup__2">
    <table class="table__1" id="tb_2">
      <tr>
        <td>CPU</td>
        <td>Intel</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>GPU</td>
        <td>RTX3050</td>
      </tr>


    </table>"
    <button type="button" class="close__btn" onclick="close__Popup2()">Close</button>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer to this is always: Delegate

the button names and classes made is non-trivial to add and remove the special__ classes

```js
const choices = document.getElementById("choices");
const buttons = choices.querySelectorAll("button");
const popupContainer = document.querySelector(".popup__container");
const recommend = document.getElementById("recommended");
//choices buttons
choices.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("button")) return; 
  const whichButton = tgt.dataset.target.replace("popup","")
  tgt.classList.add(`special__${whichButton}`);
//  document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.target).classList.add('open-Popup');
});

// close
popupContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches(".close__btn")) return; 
  const parentPopup = tgt.closest("div.popup");
  const id = parentPopup.id;
  parentPopup.classList.remove('open-Popup');
  const sourceButton = `[data-target=${id}]`;
  const className = `special__${id.replace("popup","")}`;
  document.querySelectorAll(sourceButton).forEach(button => button.classList.remove(className))
});
recommend.addEventListener("click", () => {
//  document.querySelectorAll(".popup").forEach(popup => popup.classList.add("open-Popup"));
  choices.querySelectorAll("button")
    .forEach(button => [...button.classList.entries()] // the buttons classes
      .forEach(([_,cls]) => {
        if (cls.startsWith("special__")) { // it was selected
          document.getElementById(button.dataset.target).classList.add('open-Popup');
        }
      })
    );  
});
```

```css
.special__1 {
  background-color: #4837ff;
}

.special__2 {
  background-color: #4837ff;
}

.popup {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
  color: #333;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.open-Popup {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.table__1 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.main__img_1 {
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(8, 218, 255, 0.6);
}

.close__btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 80px;
  background: hsla(204, 100%, 15%, 0.286);
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="choices">
  <h2> Choose your CPU </h2>
  <div class="mainbtn__1">
    <button type="button" class="btn__001" id="AMD" data-target="popup1">AMD</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn__001" id="Intel" data-target="popup2">Intel</button>
  </div>

  <h2> Choose your GPU </h2>
  <div class="mainbtn__2">
    <button type="button" class="btn__002" id="RTX3060" data-target="popup1">RTX3060</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn__002" id="RTX3050" data-target="popup2">RTX3050</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="popup__container">

  <button type="submit" class="popup__btn" id="recommended">Recommended</button>

  <!-- FIRST popup page -->
  <div class="popup" id="popup1">
    <table class="table__1" id="tb_1">
      <tr>
        <td>CPU</td>
        <td>AMD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>GPU</td>
        <td>RTX3060</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <button type="button" class="close__btn">Close</button>
  </div>


  <!-- second popup page -->
  <div class="popup" id="popup2">
    <table class="table__1" id="tb_2">
      <tr>
        <td>CPU</td>
        <td>Intel</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>GPU</td>
        <td>RTX3050</td>
      </tr>


    </table>
    <button type="button" class="close__btn">Close</button>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello mplungjan, I appreciate for answering my question. is it possible to modify the code in a sense whenever the user selects both the AMD button and RTX3060 button the related popup to the buttons selected is displayed only when the recommended button is pressed?

Comment: Hey, mplungjan...  I tried to use a different approach with jquery and checkboxes instead of buttons but,  no luck so far since pretty much I'm a beginner.

Comment: The two popups are consistently displayed when I press the recommended buttons and the other buttons.

Comment: Ok, fixed. You can make all this simpler by using the same class for "selected" for the buttons